# Is "Decimal.quantize" better than "round" for the same precision?

Tags: python, floating-point

I came across two methods to get precision in floating numbers - using `round` or using the `Decimal` package.

What i observed (with few examples tried in REPL) that both produce the same results:

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> 
>>> 1/3
0.3333333333333333
>>> 
>>> round(1/3)
0
>>> Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)
Decimal('0.3333333333333333333333333333')
>>> 
>>> round(1/3, 2)
0.33
>>> (Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
Decimal('0.33')
>>>
```

This makes me think which method to use out of these two. Do both the methods **always** give same the same result for the same level of precision? Or am i missing out something here?

Comment: The precision of "Decimal" can be configured and it works correctly within this precision regardless how high it is set (if there is enough memory). The precision of a float is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was able to figure out few use cases where things might be different (I will update here as I find more differences):

One use case is **division that results in recurring fractions and adding back**, say, `10 / 3`:

using `round`:

```py
>>> r = round(10/3, 2)
>>> r
3.33
>>> 
>>> sum([r, r, r])
>>> 9.99
>>>
```

using `Decimal` (case 1):

```py
>>> Q = Decimal("0.01")
>>> 
>>> d1 = Decimal(10/3)
>>> d1
Decimal('3.333333333333333481363069950020872056484222412109375')
>>> 
>>> sum([d1, d1, d1])
Decimal('10.00000000000000044408920985')
>>> 
>>> sum([d1, d1, d1]).quantize(Q)
Decimal('10.00')
>>>
```

using `Decimal` (case 2):

```py
>>> Q = Decimal("0.01")
>>> 
>>> d2 = Decimal(10) / Decimal(3)
>>> d2
Decimal('3.333333333333333333333333333')
>>> 
>>> sum([d2, d2, d2]).quantize(Q)
Decimal('10.00')
>>>
```

Second use case is when you **receive number with more decimal places than your precision value** (something similar to what [@H.Doebler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9096264/h-doebler) mentioned in his  answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70258771/4260095)). Basically exploiting the [round_half_to_even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) concept. Let's say you have set precision to 2, and get amounts like `0.125` and `0.145` and add them, the value should be `0.27`:

using `round`:

```py
>>> 0.125 + 0.145 
0.27
>>> 
>>> round(0.125, 2) + round(0.145, 2)
0.26
>>>
```

using `Decimal` (case 1 - store quantized): (**ERROR**)

```py
>>> Q = Decimal("0.01")
>>> d1 = Decimal(0.125).quantize(Q) + Decimal(0.145).quantize(Q)
>>> d1
Decimal('0.26')
>>> d1.quantize(Q)
Decimal('0.26')
>>>
```

using `Decimal` (case 2 - store raw, quantize the result): (**CORRECT**)

```py
>>> Q = Decimal("0.01")
>>> d2 = Decimal(0.125) + Decimal(0.145)
>>> d2
Decimal('0.2699999999999999900079927784')
>>> d2.quantize(Q)
Decimal('0.27')
>>>
```

I think `round` and `Decimal (case 1)` give wrong results because we are rounding (`quantizing` in case of `decimal`) the numbers **before** adding, but in case 2 we are quantizing after correctly representing the values in `Decimal`. I guess it depends a lot on **when** you quantize..

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not always give the same result:

```py
>>> (Decimal(645)/Decimal(1000)).quantize(Decimal("0.01"))
Decimal('0.64')

>>> round(645/1000, 2)
0.65
```

Builtin `float`s rely on IEEE 754 double precision floating point representation with base 2, whereas decimal uses a base 10 representation. If you really want to round exactly to decimal places, float will not work, because most non-periodic non-trivial decimal number do not lie in the `float` domain.

```py
>>> f'{round(1/3, 2):.64f}'
'0.3300000000000000155431223447521915659308433532714843750000000000'

>>> f'{(Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)).quantize(Decimal("0.01")):.64f}'
'0.3300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Comment: so you are saying that `Decimal` will always give the same exact representation for whatever precision i ask for, and `round` wont?

Comment: You can explicitly set the precision of `Decimal` in terms of decimal places using the associated `Context` object that can be retrieved via `decimal.getcontext()`. As far as I unterstand there are no limits to the precision apart from available RAM (and your time). You can also modify rounding behaviour, etc. using the `Context`.

Comment: `Decimal(645/1000).quantize(Decimal("0.01"))` returns `0.65`. I think this is because it handles `0.645` differently than `645` and `1000`.

Comment: got your point on `context`

Comment: Note however that `Decimal(645/1000) == Decimal(0.645) != Decimal(645) / Decimal(1000)`, because `645/1000` is evaluated to `float` before being handed over to the `Decimal` constructor.

Comment: yes! subtle and confusing at first, but eventually making sense..